# Is it possible to fix the number, start and end position of columns using CSS flexbox?

Tags: css, grid, flexbox, internet-explorer-11, display

I figured out late my code using grid is not functionning on IE11.
I wonder if it is possible to adapt it using flex.

[css display grid and IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47888583/css-display-grid-and-ie11/47888791?noredirect=1#comment82747209_47888791)

Using css properties of each item classes column_start_1 and column_end_7, i would like to position the item in a 12 columns grid.

If a column is used it must goes to the same line.

https://codepen.io/matoeil/pen/OzNzRK

```
<div class="field-items">
  <div class="entity entity-paragraphs-item column_start_1 column_end_7"></div>
    <div class="entity entity-paragraphs-item paragraphs-item-bloc-lien column_start_7 column_end_10">whatever</div>
    <div class="bloc-lien-item entity entity-paragraphs-item paragraphs-item-bloc-lien column_start_10 column_end_13"></div>


  <div class="bloc-lien-item supposed_to_be_above entity entity-paragraphs-item paragraphs-item-bloc-lien column_start_1 column_end_3">that block is supposed to be above since the first row has been used . This is the behaviour on other browser than IE11</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.field-items {
     display: -ms-grid;
  display:grid;
  /* grille de 12*/

 -ms-grid-columns: 8.33% 8.33% 8.33% 8.33% 8.33% 8.33% 8.33% 8.33% 8.33% 8.33% 8.33% 8.33%;
  grid-template-columns: 8.33% 8.33% 8.33% 8.33% 8.33% 8.33% 8.33% 8.33% 8.33% 8.33% 8.33% 8.33%;
  -ms-grid-rows:400px;
}

.field-items > .entity-paragraphs-item{
   border:1px solid red;
}

.bloc-lien-item {
      word-wrap: break-word;
 }

.supposed_to_be_above{
  color:blue;
}

/*    ----------    display:grid  -----------------   */
.column_start_1{
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  grid-column-start: 1;
}

.column_start_2{
  -ms-grid-column: 2;
  grid-column-start: 2;
}
.column_start_3{
  -ms-grid-column: 3;
  grid-column-start: 3;
}
.column_start_4{
  -ms-grid-column: 4;
  grid-column-start: 4;
}
.column_start_5{
  -ms-grid-column: 5;
  grid-column-start: 5;
}
.column_start_6{
  -ms-grid-column: 6;
  grid-column-start: 6;
}
.column_start_7{
  -ms-grid-column: 7;
  grid-column-start: 7;

}.column_start_8{
   -ms-grid-column: 8;
   grid-column-start: 8;
 }
.column_start_9{
  -ms-grid-column: 9;
  grid-column-start: 9;
}
.column_start_10{
  -ms-grid-column: 10;
  grid-column-start: 10;
}
.column_start_11{
  -ms-grid-column: 11;
  grid-column-start: 11;
}
.column_start_12{
  -ms-grid-column: 12;
  grid-column-start: 12;
}

/**/

.column_end_1{
  -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  grid-column-end: 1;
}

.column_end_2{
  -ms-grid-column-span: 2;
  grid-column-end: 2;
}
.column_end_3{
  -ms-grid-column-span: 3;
  grid-column-end: 3;
}
.column_end_4{
  -ms-grid-column-span: 4;
  grid-column-end: 4;
}
.column_end_5{
  -ms-grid-column-span: 5;
  grid-column-end: 5;
}
.column_end_6{
  -ms-grid-column-span: 6;
  grid-column-end: 6;
}
.column_end_7{
  -ms-grid-column-span: 7;
  grid-column-end: 7;

}.column_end_8{
   -ms-grid-column-span: 8;
   grid-column-end: 8;
 }
.column_end_9{
  -ms-grid-column-span: 9;
  grid-column-end: 9;
}
.column_end_10{
  -ms-grid-column-span: 10;
  grid-column-end: 10;
}
.column_end_11{
  -ms-grid-column-span: 11;
  grid-column-end: 11;
}
.column_end_12{
  -ms-grid-column-span: 12;
  grid-column-end: 12;
}
.column_end_13{
  -ms-grid-column-span: 13;
  grid-column-end: 13;
}
```

Comment: Flexbox doesn't define a grid in the same way Grid does, but you can use the same logic that many framework does, using `col_1/col_2` etc. This sample produce a similar output using Flexbox: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wpGywo

Comment: You're using the CSS Grid syntax not flexbox...and the answer is "NO".

Comment: Btw, the item called `supposed_to_be_above`, you must mean _below_?, since it is how it renders with Grid on Chrome.

Comment: yes below sorry

Comment: Let me know if the codepen from my first comment is a solution that works, and I post it as an answer.

Comment: that's great ;) the only thing i see missing from the grid option is it does not allow to leave blank columns on the row , https://codepen.io/matoeil/pen/mpPXmE vs https://codepen.io/matoeil/pen/OzNzRK. Any idea?

Comment: Posted an answer with a 2nd sample how you could do to enable _blank_ items. It is also possible with e.g. adding extra margins etc. on one of the elements, though the CSS to make those behave when it comes to wrapping etc., an extra element is way, way simpler and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox doesn't define a grid in the same way CSS Grid does, but you could use the same logic that many framework does, using `col_1/col_2` etc.

This sample produce a similar output using Flexbox

Stack snippet

```css
.field-items {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;  
}

.field-items > .entity-paragraphs-item{
  border:1px solid red;  
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.bloc-lien-item {
  word-wrap: break-word;
 }

.supposed_to_be_above{
  color:blue;
}

/*    ----------    grid  -----------------   */
.col_1{
  width: 8.333%;
}
.col_2{
  width: 16.667%;
}
.col_3{
  width: 25%;
}

.col_6{
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="field-items">
  <div class="entity entity-paragraphs-item col_6"></div>
  <div class="entity entity-paragraphs-item paragraphs-item-bloc-lien col_3">whatever</div>
  <div class="bloc-lien-item entity entity-paragraphs-item paragraphs-item-bloc-lien col_3"></div>


  <div class="bloc-lien-item supposed_to_be_above entity entity-paragraphs-item paragraphs-item-bloc-lien col_3">that block is supposed to be above since the first row has been used . This is the behaviour on other browser than IE11</div>
</div>
```

---

To get make *blank* items, you could use an empty element, and simply use the `col_*` class on it.

*Optionally, one can use e.g. `margin` to create "empty" spaces, though I find it way simpler to just drop in a "blank item" element.*

*To be noted, `margin` using percent on flex items does not render the same result cross browsers, and because of that might not be a valid solution.*

Stack snippet

```css
.field-items {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;  
}

.field-items > .entity-paragraphs-item{
  border:1px solid red;  
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.bloc-lien-item {
  word-wrap: break-word;
 }

.supposed_to_be_above{
  color:blue;
}

/*    ----------    grid  -----------------   */
.col_1{
  width: 8.333%;
}
.col_2{
  width: 16.667%;
}
.col_3{
  width: 25%;
}

.col_6{
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="field-items">
  <div class="entity entity-paragraphs-item col_6"></div>
  <div class="col_3"></div>
  <div class="entity entity-paragraphs-item paragraphs-item-bloc-lien col_3">whatever</div>

  <div class="bloc-lien-item supposed_to_be_above entity entity-paragraphs-item paragraphs-item-bloc-lien col_3">that block is supposed to be above since the first row has been used . This is the behaviour on other browser than IE11</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks. Is there no flex value that would make the div start further?

Comment: @Matoeil No, there isn't...that's why we got CSS Grid :)